# Replacement for removed bind1st in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17

I had this usage of `bind1st` but I upgrade my project to C++17 as `bind1st` is removed.

How can I replace `bind1st` in the following statement?
Lambda?

```
DBManager::Instance().FuncQuery(std::bind1st(std::mem_fn(&CGuild::LoadGuildData), this), "SELECT master, level, exp, name, skill_point, skill, sp, ladder_point, win, draw, loss, gold FROM guild WHERE id = %u", m_data.guild_id);
```

Comment: What parameters does the function expect? Can you provide information about the API you are calling?

Comment: [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12) is shown an example where the deprecated function is replaced by a lambda. Without any further information is difficult to say how it could work in your use case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use [std::bind](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/):

```
std::bind(std::mem_fn(&CGuild::LoadGuildData), this, std::placeholders::_1)
```

And you can remove the superfluous `std::mem_fn` too:

```
std::bind(&CGuild::LoadGuildData, this, std::placeholders::_1)
```

Comment: You don't need `mem_fn` in this context

Comment: @Barry True, but it wasn't needed in the original either ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 8):

With lambda, you might replace

```
std::bind1st(std::mem_fn(&CGuild::LoadGuildData), this)
```

by

```
[this](auto&& data) {return this->LoadGuildData(data);}
```

which give at the end something like:

```
DBManager::Instance().FuncQuery(
     [this](auto&& data) {return this->LoadGuildData(data);},
     "SELECT master, level, exp, name, skill_point, skill, sp, "
     "ladder_point, win, draw, loss, gold FROM guild WHERE id = %u",
     m_data.guild_id);
```

Comment: You'll know this, but I'll point out for readers that including the `this->` in the call is not necessary, since names within a lambda that captures `this` will be looked up in the class scope automatically anyway.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you could do here. And I find it really unfortunate that the current state of affairs is so awkward.

---

The most direct substitution is to take your `bind1st` and convert it exactly to `bind`:

```
std::bind(&CGuild::LoadGuildData, this, std::placeholders::_1)
```

Or, if you use `bind` semi-regularly, you probably will bring in the placeholders via `using` in some form or other, so this becomes:

```
std::bind(&CGuild::LoadGuildData, this, _1)
```

This is actually strictly better than `bind1st` since this forwards its argument, but `bind1st` would not.

---

The other thing we could do is a lambda. And here, it depends on what `LoadGuildData()` does exactly. If it returns an object and you don't care about how this bound callable gets used necessarily, you can just write:

```
[this](auto const& arg){ return LoadGuildData(arg); }
```

This will work, most of the time. But it's not exactly the same thing as the bind expression. If `LoadGuildData()` returned something like an `int&`, the bind expression would return an `int&`, but this version returns an `int`. That might not be important. It might be not be. But if it is, you have to add, at least:

```
[this](auto const& arg) -> decltype(auto) { return LoadGuildData(arg); }
```

This will either return a reference type or not a reference type depending on what `LoadGuildData()` actually returns.

Now... the argument, `arg`, might be required to be a modifiable reference, which necessitates

```
[this](auto&& arg) -> decltype(auto) { return LoadGuildData(arg); }
```

But sufficiently often, you might need something more. You might need to use this callable in a context that needs to check if it's callable. Right now, due to the rules of how this checking works - all the lambdas I've written will claim that they're callable with any argument at all. Regardless of what `LoadGuildData()` actually takes. But if it's the wrong type, you'll get a hard compile error. Unfortunate.

So what you really need to do, to write a lambda that has the same behavior as the bind expression I wrote earlier, is:

```
[this](auto&& arg) -> decltype(LoadGuildData(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg))) {
    return LoadGuildData(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg));
}
```

Actually, it's not quite the same behavior. This lambda is actually better in some ways - because the bind expression would not have worked if `LoadGuildData()` were a member function template or an overload set or took a default argument - but the lambda works in all of these cases. Which is why it is so often recommend to use lambdas - they always work, they're usually the best solution, and they're sometimes the only solution.

But it's a huge mouthful, which is why so many code bases use macros. Like [`BOOST_HOF_RETURNS`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/returns.html):

```
#define FWD(...) static_cast<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)&&>(__VA_ARGS__)
[this](auto&& arg) BOOST_HOF_RETURNS(LoadGuildData(FWD(arg)))
```

---

All of which is to say... we can't have nice things.

Answer (score 2):

I would just go with lambdas and skip using `bind` since that seems likely to be deprecated as well.

We can from the proposal that deprecated `bind1st` which is [n4190](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4190.htm), it says in the section `III. What Must Die`:

> D.9 "Binders" [depr.lib.binders]
>
> This defines bind1st()/bind2nd(), which **were strictly superseded by
>   bind()**. (In the future, **I'll argue that bind() itself has been
>   superseded by lambdas and especially generic lambdas, so bind() should
>   be deprecated**, but that isn't part of this proposal.)

Note the document [Changes between C++14 and C++17](http://open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0636r2.html#removed) tell us which proposals deprecated what.

So that would look something like:

```
[this](...) {return this->LoadGuildData(...);}. // ... needs to be filled in based
                                                // on implementation
```